# Recreating default exchanges in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

So... I was messing around on my localhost, and deleted the "/" vhost. Now I'm curious: What do you need to do to recreate the default exchange? Is it possible, or is `rabbitmqctl reset` the only recourse?

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ adds the default exchanges to every new vhost, so you can just re-create the vhost and the default exchanges will be there.

I verified this just now, by deleting the `/` vhost on my local RMQ and then re-creating it. all of the default exchanges are back, the way they should be.

---

also, FWIW, I would recommend not using the `/` vhost anyways. you should be creating a new vhost for each system you are building. so, really, it doesn't matter that you deleted `/` because you shouldn't be using it.